# Sending data from a delegate to a view controller in Objective-C on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Note: I've only been using Objective-C for a week.

Here's my end goal: I want to call out to a server and grab a json file that has urls and url descriptions in it. If I can't get that file, I want to show an error view. If I can get that file, I want to display its contents in a table view.

Restrictions: I'm doing this in a Cocoa Touch Static Library (by requirement) to be included in a larger app that will load it "like" an app.

What I'm doing right now is I'm using Reachability to check for a connection to the host. Then I'm opening an NSURLConnection for the file. Once the file is gotten, I parse the json using the json-framework. The datatype of the jsonObject is id (afaik that means *).

Currently, ALL of that is happening in the Delegate. If I get errors with connection or file retrieval, I set the rootView to the error view controller. Otherwise, I set the rootView to my other view.

I've tried the method of setting the jsonObject to extern in the view controller, but that didn't work. I tried setting a property in the view controller and setting the jsonObject in the controller after I create it, but the jsonObject is nil at that point and everything blows up with some error regarding incorrect selectors or something.

Am I even headed in the right direction with this? How SHOULD this be done?

**EDIT**

My view controller is typed as UINavigationController and I stick whichever view controller I end up using into it. When I try to call a setter in my view controller, I have to cast the UINavigationController to my view type to be able to see the setter, but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
SpringboardApplication[5850:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setJsonObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x602ed20'
```

I am calling it as follows:

```
[(LU_SOCLINKS_RootViewController *) root_navigation_controller setJsonObject:jsonObject];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "delegate" you mean the app delegate? I assume that the view controller is in an instance variable in your app delegate, in which case you just need to create a setter method in the view controller that you can use to pass the data.

In the view controller:

.h

```
- (void)setData:(NSData/NSString/whatever *)data;
```

.m

```
- (void)setData:(NSData/NSString/whatever *)data {
    vcData = [data retain];
    // do stuff with the data
}
```

In the app delegate

```
[viewController setData:theData];
```

This is a simplistic answer. Am I understanding your problem correctly?

Comment: I will try this specifically, but I have tried setting a property and @synthesize in the .m file for the view controller.

.h had 
"id jsonObject;"
and .m had
"@synthesize jsonObject;"

But calling viewController.jsonObject = myObject caused it to get very angry about selectors (maybe because myObject was nil at the time?)

Comment: …reread your question. synthesizing the property should work fine. Why/where is the JSON object nil in your view controller? Perhaps that's the real problem. You need to retain it so you can successfully pass it to the view controller.

Comment: I edited my question to give some more details. The program seems to not be seeing my cast.

Comment: The console error message is telling you that the view controller is actually a UINavigationController, not a LU_SOCLINKS_RootViewController. Casting the variable doesn't change the value.

Comment: So, if root_nagivation_controller is a UINavigationController and I set root_navigation_controller = LU_SOCLINKS_RootViewController, why can I not cast the variable to access the members of LU_SOCLINKS_RootViewController?

Comment: If the view controller *were* an instance of LU_SOCLINKS_RootViewController, then you *could*, but the error message means that it's **not**. It's a UINavigationController. Post the code where you create this view controller.

Comment: Oh my goodness... I see. I'm using [UINavigationController alloc] and initWithRootViewContoller to set the viewController. root_navigation_controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: [LU_SOCLINKS_RootViewController alloc]]; Do you know how I can reference the viewController inside?

Comment: Post that whole block of setup code to your question and I'll take a closer look.

Comment: I don't know that anyone else will have this problem. I was mistaking the passing of the ViewController as a parameter to UINavController as actually creating the ViewController in the place of the NavController. I now am creating the viewController separately, setting the property on it, and then creating the NavController.

Thank you for helping me work through this!

Comment: Phew. Glad you were able to sort through it!

Comment: I need to get a book. haha  Thanks for your help, Charlie.